# Apache header Content-Type vendor specific type/json

Tags: php, rest, apache, http-headers

I am quite confused with the Content-Type vendor specific. Say by default,

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

but with vendor specific type, I can have this

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.anything.process-v1+json
```

Do I need to have any special function to do in PHP to use if I would check if the Content-Type is not vendor specific?

Comment: I can say both. Thanks for the reply **Martijn**.

Answer (score 2):

If you are accepting content via HTTP POST from a client you can check the content type with $_SERVER['CONTENT_TYPE']. I would encourage you to use the @ver attribute in the Content-Type header instead of embedding in your vendor content type name. Example:

```
Content-Type: application/vnd.anything.process+json;ver=1
```

If you are sending content to a server via HTTP POST you need to specify an accept header to tell the client to return the data in the vendor specific content type. Something like this would work:

```
header('Accept: application/vnd.anything.process+json;ver=1');
```

Accept headers can be quite complicated though. If you do not control the server you are posting to as client, you should provide a sensible default to your Accept header. Something like this is more friendly if you want the server to send back plain JSON if it doesn't understand the vendor header:

```
header('Accept: application/vnd.anything.process+json;ver=1;q=0.9, application/json;q=0.1');
```

The most permissive Accept headers accept anything though:

```
header('Accept: application/vnd.anything.process+json;ver=1;q=0.9, application/json;q=0.5, */*;q=0.1');
```

Here is the actual RFC for Accept headers: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html